# Nodejs file attachement handler

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, carrierwave, gcloud, gm

I am looking for resources for file attachment handling in nodeJs. 
I am from rails background so there are two popular resources which do things out of the box for developers ex. carrier wave and the paperclip. they provide pretty straight integrations with s3 and Google cloud storage. 
I want to achieve similar in node didn't find any useful resource.

I am using graphicmagik https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm for image version generation. I have to generate two version of an original image 
500*500 and 300*300. and upload an image to Gcloud with image URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Multer with expressJS for handling file upload in NodeJS.
Here is the package: [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Comment: Multer does not provide image resizing options. 
I achieved this using  multer + graphicsmagik